# Proving $a^b$ is well defined

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, exponentiation

How do I prove that $$\lim_{(m,n) \to \infty} a_m^{b_n} = a^b$$

where $a,b \in \mathbb R$, $a_i,b_i \in \mathbb Q$, $a_m \to a$, $b_n \to b$ and $a$ and $b$ are not both zero, and $a_m >0$

I can prove it with $n$ or $m$ constant by using continuity, but not when both are limiting at the same time.

Comment: Are you trying to prove that that limit is well defined and that it does not depend on the choice of rational sequences $a_m$, $b_n$, or are you trying to prove that exponentiation is continuous assuming the existence of the map $$(0,+\infty)\times(0,+\infty)\ni (a,b)\mapsto a^b\in (0,+\infty)\quad ?$$

Comment: @G.Sassatelli That it is independent of the choice of sequence.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Fixed.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on what you already "know".

First, there's another condition you probably meant to add in. You probably want to assume that $a_m > 0$. Otherwise, you can have things like $(-2)^{1/2}=\sqrt{2}i$ appear. If you assume that $a_m>0$ for all $m$, then $a_m\to a>0$ follows as well.

If you know continuity of the exponential and natural log functions, this is pretty straightforward.

$a_m^{b_n}=e^{\ln(a_m^{b_n})}=e^{b_n\ln(a_m)}$

Now *assuming* $e^x$ is continuous and $\ln(x)$ is continuous, we have that $y\ln(x)$ is continuous since the product of continuous functions is continuous and so $e^{y\ln(x)}$ is continuous since the composition of continuous functions is continuous.

Now that we know $f(x,y)=e^{y\ln(x)}$ is continuous, $(a_m,b_n) \to (a,b)$ implies that $f(a_m,b_n) \to f(a,b)$ and there's your result.

Comment: Thanks, sorry for stupid q but where does this fail when a=b=0?

Comment: Undefined because ln(0) is undefined.